# Filter/Sort the classes in problems view based on author in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, filter

I need to filter or sort the warnings in problems,Tasks view based on the author names given in the class.[@author userName]. Is there any way i could configure it. If not can some one give direction to extend the view and add my own either filter or sorting.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesnt seem to be a way to do this by default, but extending the problems view to add this information seems feasible. See this for example: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=881

Comment: +1 for the useful info. although i do not have info about creating these extensions.T